# How to catch specified exception, display warning and logout effectively?

Tags: flutter, exception, widget, flutter-web, bloc

Web application contains many screens with list views and edit dialogs for edit selected records. List view uses "standard display behavour" using `StreamBuilder`.

Simplified `bloc.dart`

```dart
class Bloc {
  final _subject = StreamController<Data>.broadcast();
  Stream<Data> get data => _subject.asyncMap(_getData);

  Future<Data> _getData(...) {
    try {
      final data = await api.getUrl(...);
      return data;
    } on SomeException catch (e) {
      // This exception is catched by StreamBuilder
      throw ApiException('could not get data');
    }
  }
}
```

Simplified `widget.dart`

```dart
StreamBuilder<...>(
  stream: bloc.data,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      // Bloc throws an exception which thrown by API client (HttpClient).
      return ErrorWidget(snapshot.error.toString());
    }
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(...);
    } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  }
),
```

Each edit dialog uses `showDialog` to display selected item details and save modifications.
There may be a situation when (for example) access token is invalid (or expired) **during** his *already authenticated* session. It is necessary to inform user about this (showing him a warning) and after closing warning destroy the session and return to *login* screen. **Is it possible** to implement **effective solution** to **catch** specific exception (eg. `TokenInvalidException`) in a **single** place **without** adding symbolic code like:

```dart
if (snapshot.error is TokenInvalidException) {
  // destroy session
  // return to Login
}
```

into **each** `StreamBuilder` list view and some code to check *if exception occurred* on **each** `Dialog`'s save action?

I have 100500 screens and I do not want to implement the same code for each screen. Actually I want some global exception catcher which catches the required exception and executes specific action.

Now I see some global `StreamController` with stream which accepts such exception (events) and is listen by some global parent widget (*MaterialApp* or maybe *Main*).

```dart
final globalExceptionController = StreamController<TokenInvalidException>.broadcast();

// somewhere
globalExceptionController.stream.listen((e) async {
  // Show warning
  final result = await showDialog(...);
  // Go to login
  Navigator.pushReplacement(context, <login page route>);
}) {}
```

The problem I see here is the *bloc object* which throws the exception will have strong dependency on stream controller which is not interested to it absolutely. But actually I need to link somehow the `bloc` and `GUI` because to show warning and switch the route I need a `context`.

Any ideas or critics are appreciated.

Comment: snapshot.error is an object you can check for runtime type to know which is the error being thrown for example `if(error is FirebaseAuthException)`

Comment: @Yadu, I know this. Did you read my question?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the coordinator bloc pattern described [here](https://medium.com/prime-holding-jsc/building-complex-apps-in-flutter-with-the-power-of-reactive-programming-54a38fbc0cde) helps you with this problem